# Get object by reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, c#-4.0, system.reflection

I'm looking for mechanism in c# works like that:

```
Car car1;
Car car2;

Car car = (Car)SomeMechanism.Get("car1");
```

car1 and car2 are fields

So I want to get some object with reflection, not type :/ How can I do it in c# ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking...

Comment: I think you need a little more context - is car1 and car2 a field, or a local? If they are locals, then @Jason is correct - you cannot do this. More importantly, why would you want to do this with locals?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible for local variables but If you have a field, you can do

```
class Foo{

    public Car car1;
    public Car car2;
}
```

you can do

```
object fooInstance = ...;

Car car1 = (Car)fooInstance.GetType().GetField("car1").GetValue(fooInstance);
```

Comment: Is there way to make this field's not public ?

Comment: @piotrek yes. `Car car1 = (Car)fooInstance.GetType().GetField("car1").GetValue(fooInstance, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);` to get non-public fields.

Comment: @BalaR There is a typo. You meant `Car car1 = (Car)fooInstance.GetType().GetField("car1",BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(fooInst‌​ance);`

Comment: How about now in 2017 ?

Comment: why would you do that when you have already got `fooInstance` ?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to access local variables by reflection. This is not possible. Local variables are not accessible by reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Am I correct to assume that you have two variables and that you want to get one or the other dynamically? I don't believe you can do this with reflection (at least not easily), but you can do it with functions quite easily.

```
// Declaration
class SomeMechanism
{
    public static T Get<T>(Func<T> getter);
}

// Usage
Car car1;
Car car2;

Car car = SomeMechanism.Get(() => car1);
```