# Can i Do object reflection in C#

Tags: c#

I have two classes, Dog and Cat

```
class Dog
{
    public void speak() {
         System.out.println("Woof!");
    }
}
class Cat
{
    public void speak() {
         System.out.print("Meow!");
    }
}
```

In my main, I take the name as String, either "Cat", or "Dog".

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = sc.next();
    Class<?> cls = Class.forName(name);
    Object object = cls.newInstance();
}
```

Can i do this in C#??

Comment: Yes there is the possibility to do so, but why don't you use an inheritance approach for this example?

Comment: you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252510/get-object-by-reflection but you have to add another third class.

Comment: Are you sure it is `C#`? `System.out.print()` seems like `Java` ?

Comment: @Berkay He never said it was written in C#, He asks if it possible to do the same in C# which makes huge difference

Comment: My point; where is the `C#` code that he tried. @m.rogalski

Comment: this is just an example of code that shows actually what i want to  do in c#,so this is not in C#

Answer (score 2):

Line by line it would be:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name = Console.ReadLine();

    // The second true will ignore case
    var cls = Type.GetType("Animals." + name, true, true);

    var @object = Activator.CreateInstance(cls);
}
```

with the various animals like:

```
namespace Animals
{
    public class Dog
    {
        public void speak()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Woof!");
        }
    }

    public class Cat
    {
        public void speak()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Meow!");
        }
    }
}
```

I've added a namespace to make it a "more complete" example: in .NET you can have your code *outside" any namespace, but normally you'll use a namespace. I'm prepending it to the name of the class obtained from the console (`"Animals." + name`).

Note that this code is quite useless, because without a base `interface`/`class`, you can't easily make them `speak()` (you can go full reflection/dynamic from this point onward to do it but it is "bad")

Bad way with dynanic:

```
dynamic @object = Activator.CreateInstance(cls);
@object.speak();
```

(note that **I'm not supporting what you are doing**, it is bad in multiple ways)

Comment: thanks @xanatos Now i solved that problem and it's Working

Comment: Hello @xanatos Can you suggest me how to pass parameters in this context?

Comment: @tejas If you follow the `dynamic` way, `@object.speak(3)`